# Chat avatar reputation discrepancy

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, chat

In Ask Different chat, my reputation against my avatar is different to my reputation in my account on Ask Different, and the addition of all my points across all accounts and other users are seeing different (and more accurate numbers).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Chat tends to lag a bit behind the network when it comes to updating the total rep.

I forced a refresh on your chat profile from the main site and it looks like that did the trick.

Comment: http://twitter.com/balpha/status/38717485729456128

Comment: @balpha Words to live by.